# Which linker setting determines the load path of a shared library?

Tags: c++, macos, linker, shared-libraries, poco

I have built the Poco C++ library on Mac. When inspecting the built output files I notice that their load paths are absolute paths that point to the build directory. For example:

```
$ otool -L libPocoFoundation.dylib
libPocoFoundation.dylib:
    /Users/francis/orig/poco-1.3.6p2/lib/Darwin/i386/libPocoFoundation.9.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.0)
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.9.0)
    /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 625.0.0)
```

Which compiler or linker option determined this? How can I override this? (At compile time. I know that I can change it afterwards with the `install_name_tool`.)

**Edit**
The compiler is `g++-4.0` (gcc version 4.0.1 Apple).

The linker is `libtool` (Apple Computer, Inc. version cctools-782)

I'm perusing the makefiles currently. Perhaps I'll figure it out myself. But all help is welcome!

Comment: Please specify a compiler/linker...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related question at stackoverflow.com ["How to set the runtime path (-rpath) of an executable with gcc under Mac OSX?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513799/how-to-set-the-runtime-path-rpath-of-an-executable-with-gcc-under-mac-osx) explains some ways to do it at compile-time.

BTW: I've reproduced your POCO bug on MacOS Leopard and opened a [bug 3164792](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3164792&group_id=132964&atid=725709) for POCO-1.4.0