# How to set the runtime path (-rpath) of an executable with gcc under Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, gcc, linker, shared-libraries, dyld

I want to set under Mac OSX the runtime path of an executable (for the linker) at compile time, such that shared libraries at non-standard locations are found by the dynamic linker at program start.

Under Linux this is possible with `-Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /path/to` (or using `-Wl,-rpath,/path/to`) and under Solaris you can add `-R/path/to` to the compiler command line.

I found [some information](http://blogs.oracle.com/dipol/entry/dynamic_libraries_rpath_and_mac) that Mac OS X gcc has -rpath support since 10.5, i.e. since ~ 2008.

I tried to get it working with a minimal example - without success:

```
$ cat blah.c 
int blah(int b)
{
  return b+1;
}
```

And:

```
$ cat main.c 

#include <stdio.h>

int blah(int);

int main ()
{
  printf("%d\n", blah(22));
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled it like this:

```
$ gcc -c  blah.c
$ gcc -dynamiclib blah.o -o libblah.dylib
$ gcc main.c -lblah -L`pwd`  -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker `pwd`/t
```

Now the test:

```
$ mkdir t
$ mv libblah.dylib t
$ ./a.out
dyld: Library not loaded: libblah.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/max/test/./a.out
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap
```

Thus the question: How to I set the runtime path for the linker under Mac OSX?

Btw, setting `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` works - but I don't want to use this hack.

**Edit:** Regarding `otool -L`:

```
$ otool -L a.out 
a.out:
        libblah.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.1)
```

It seems that `otool -L` only prints the library names (and probable the locations at link time) the executable was linked against and no runtime path information.

Comment: I don't have an OS X system but searching around, [install_name_tool](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/install_name_tool.1.html) can add rpaths to your binary.  Not sure why yours isn't working — what does `otool -L` say?

Comment: Use `otool -l <file>` and search for the `LC_RPATH` sections to see the paths that a binary (library or exe) is setup to search for dependent libs.

Comment: This page is helpful to understand rpath on Mac: [https://blog.krzyzanowskim.com/2018/12/05/rpath-what/](https://blog.krzyzanowskim.com/2018/12/05/rpath-what/)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Found by experimentation, and inspecting the command lines generated by Xcode for a [reference rpath demo project by Dave Driblin](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2009/11/15/rpath/):

`otool -L` shows you the install name of the linked libraries. To get `@rpath` to work, you need to change the install name of the library:

```
$ gcc -dynamiclib blah.o -install_name @rpath/t/libblah.dylib -o libblah.dylib
$ mkdir t ; mv libblah.dylib t/
$ gcc main.c -lblah -L`pwd`/t -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker `pwd`
```

Comment: Yes, this works. Given that there are existing semantics of -rpath on other Unix-like OS, Apples deviating implementation seems a bit awkward. At least they should document it in their version of the gcc man-page.

Comment: @Karel is correct, but [this](http://dev.lsstcorp.org/trac/wiki/LinkingDarwin) might be helpful as well, if you want a more complete list of alternatives.

Comment: Use `otool -l <file>` and search for the `LC_RPATH` sections to see the paths that a binary (library or exe) is setup to search for dependent libs.

Comment: @cdunn2001 Your link appears to be dead.

Comment: @dstromberg, You're right. But [this](https://matthew-brett.github.io/docosx/mac_runtime_link.html) links the same dead link with more elucidation and explains how to use `install_name_tool`, which is what I use to set the rpath.