# Why is this Mac OS X rpath command not working?

Tags: macos, linker, rpath

I'm trying to use rpath to link in some libraries for an app. Some of the rpaths work others don't.

I have two dynamic libraries I'm linking to `libgunrock` and `libtd` both in different directories.

My link like looks like the following:

```
gcc -L/Users/aterrel/workspace/apps/gunrock/build/lib/ -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/Users/aterrel/workspace/apps/gunrock/build/lib/ -lgunrock  -L/Users/aterrel/workspace/apps/xdata/xlang/thunderdome -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/Users/aterrel/workspace/apps/xdata/xlang/thunderdome -ltd  app-c-gunrock-bokeh.o -o app
```

The load paths are correct. The relavant parts of the `otool -l app`:

```
Load command 16
          cmd LC_RPATH
      cmdsize 64
         path /Users/aterrel/workspace/apps/gunrock/build/lib/ (offset 12)
Load command 17
          cmd LC_RPATH
      cmdsize 72
         path /Users/aterrel/workspace/apps/xdata/xlang/thunderdome (offset 12)
Load command 18
```

Yet I still get the error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libtd.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/aterrel/workspace/apps/xdata/xlang/webgraph/apps/c-gunrock-bokeh/./app
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

If I run with `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/aterrel/workspace/apps/xdata/xlang/thunderdome` app works fine.

I don't understand why `libgunrock.dylib` is loaded fine but `libtd.dylib` is not.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513799/how-to-set-the-runtime-path-rpath-of-an-executable-with-gcc-under-mac-osx?rq=1) SO answer helpful?

Comment: I hadn't checked the install name. Thanks I'll look at that now.