# Homebrew refusing to link OpenSSL

Tags: macos, openssl, homebrew, .net-core

I'm on: OSX 10.11.6, Homebrew version 0.9.9m OpenSSL 0.9.8zg 14 July 2015

I'm trying to play with with dotnetcore and by following their [instructions](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos),

I've upgraded/installed the latest version of openssl:

```
> brew install openssl
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/openssl-1.0.2h_1.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/Homebrew/openssl-1.0.2h_1.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring openssl-1.0.2h_1.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
A CA file has been bootstrapped using certificates from the system
keychain. To add additional certificates, place .pem files in
  /usr/local/etc/openssl/certs

and run
  /usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/c_rehash

This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local.

Apple has deprecated use of OpenSSL in favor of its own TLS and crypto libraries

Generally there are no consequences of this for you. If you build your
own software and it requires this formula, you'll need to add to your
build variables:

    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

But when I try to link openssl I continue to run into this linking error:

```
> brew link --force openssl
Warning: Refusing to link: openssl
Linking keg-only OpenSSL means you may end up linking against the insecure,
deprecated system version while using the headers from the Homebrew version.
Instead, pass the full include/library paths to your compiler e.g.:
  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
```

The option to include compiler flags doesn't make sense to me, since I'm not compiling these libraries that I'm dependent on.

**EDIT** dotnetcore has updated their instructions:

```
brew update    
brew install openssl    
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/    
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/
```

Comment: For .NET Core you need a supported version of OpenSSL, which would be a 1.0.1 or 1.0.2 version.  Since you're reporting a 0.9.8 version maybe you need to `brew upgrade openssl` first?

Comment: I've already done that. I should have clarified, but I didn't add those steps to the question. But I've already done the `brew update` and  `brew install openssl`. This is trying to install the supported version.

Comment: Looks like Homebrew has explicitly blocked it: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/commit/b999edb3448793529aea8b29c01b3851bbc3b3eb.

Comment: Perhaps using a different HOMEBREW_PREFIX would work; but that's definitely beyond my experience.

Comment: And.. to continue rounding out my rambling, you might be interested in whatever develops on https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/pull/597

Comment: *"... when I try to link openssl I continue to run into this linking error:.."* - Also see [How to set the runtime path (-rpath) of an executable with gcc under Mac OSX?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4513799). It may help you always load the correct library at runtime, if Brew is not adding it.

Comment: @bartonjs - the linking worked with 1.0.1 version. As per the commit you posted, which was just a few days ago, my guess is that the older versions have a different HOMEBREW_PREFIX. I'm good for now, but in the future I'll try your suggestion of trying a different prefix.

Comment: I tried most of the solutions on this page, and none worked. I was however able to get .Net core working with this solution: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3964#issuecomment-236485454

Comment: @PaulKeister's link to the github discussion worked for me. Basically just run: `sudo install_name_tool -add_rpath /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.0/System.Security.Cryptography.Native.dylib`

Comment: The `rpath` solution is better. There’s a reason Homebrew now prevents you from linking OpenSSL; it *is* a bad idea and may break stuff on your computer.

Comment: You should probably put your "dotnetcore has updated their install instructions" into an answer here to your own question :\

Answer (score 64, accepted):

As the update to the other answer suggests, the workaround of installing the old openssl101 brew will no longer work.  For a right-now workaround, see [this comment on dotnet/cli#3964](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3964#issuecomment-236493536).

The most relevant part of the issue copied here:

> I looked into the other option that was suggested for setting the rpath on the library. I think the following is a better solution that will only effect this specific library.
>
> `sudo install_name_tool -add_rpath /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.0/System.Security.Cryptography.Native.dylib`
>
> and/or if you have NETCore 1.0.1 installed perform the same command for 1.0.1 as well:
>
> `sudo install_name_tool -add_rpath /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.1/System.Security.Cryptography.Native.dylib`
>
> In effect, rather than telling the operating system to always use the homebrew version of SSL and potentially causing something to break, we're telling dotnet how to find the correct library.

Also importantly, it looks like Microsoft are aware of the issue and and have both a) a somewhat immediate plan to mitigate as well as b) a long-term solution (probaby bundling OpenSSL with dotnet).

Another thing to note: `/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib` is where the brew is linked by default:

```
13:22 $ ls -l /usr/local/opt/openssl
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ben  admin  26 May 15 14:22 /usr/local/opt/openssl -> ../Cellar/openssl/1.0.2h_1
```

If for whatever reason you install the brew and link it in a different location, then that path is the one you should use as an rpath.

Once you've update the rpath of the System.Security.Cryptography.Native.dylib libray, you'll need to restart your interactive session (i.e., close your console and start another one).

Comment: Where am I supposed to add that line? I'm trying to get this to work in CI. I'm getting a `/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.0/System.Security.Cryptography.Native.dylib (No such file or directory)`.

Comment: @mrahhal that's the installation path of the `dotnet` tooling.  Its possible that you either don't have it installed or you installed or to another location.  If its installed and on your part, you could use `which dotnet` to find it.

Comment: Oh, just realized I'm adding this line before installing `dotnet`. Will retry and come back.

Comment: Worked for me, in my case the sdk was installed to a different directory so I had to change the path.

Comment: With dotnet 1.1.0 I had to do: `sudo install_name_tool -add_rpath /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.1.0/System.Security.Cryptography.Native.OpenSsl.dylib`

Comment: What if `which dotnet` reveals I don't have it?

Comment: @macloo I've heard reports from acquaintances that the installer on macOS sometimes doesn't properly update the path, so you may have it on your file system but unable to use it normally.  The other possibility is that you really don't have it, in which case you should install it from http://dot.net.

Answer (score 74):

This is what worked for me:

```
brew update
brew install openssl
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2j/bin/openssl /usr/local/bin/openssl
```

Thanks to @dorlandode on this thread https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/pull/597

NB: I only used this as a temporary fix until I could spend time correctly installing Openssl again from scratch. As I remember I spent best part of a day debugging and having issues before I realised the best way was to manually install the certs I needed one by one. Please read the link in @bouke's comment before attempting this.

Comment: is the full path for the last link `/usr/local/bin/openssl`?

Comment: Why this answer is not accepted, you saved my life man. ::thumb up::

Comment: There's a good reason brew is refusing to do this. See also this: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/pull/597.

Comment: This solution worked for me, but I had to change `1.0.2j` to `1.0.2k` because of version differences. So users beware, you may need to adjust paths for the current version

Comment: I saw @Jeff's comment a little too late. If you did too, I believe `ln -s -f /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2k/bin/openssl /usr/local/bin/openssl` fixes it

Comment: I'm using macOS Catalina 10.15.4 and this is the only solution that worked.

Answer (score 52):

None of these solutions worked for me on OS X El Capitan 10.11.6. Probably because OS X has a native version of openssl that it believes is superior, and as such, does not like tampering.

So, I took the high road and started fresh...

---

## Manually install and symlink

```
cd /usr/local/src
```

- If you're getting "No such file or directory", make it:

  `cd /usr/local && mkdir src && cd src`

Download openssl:

```
curl --remote-name https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2h.tar.gz
```

Extract and cd in:

```
tar -xzvf openssl-1.0.2h.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.0.2h
```

Compile and install:

```
./configure darwin64-x86_64-cc --prefix=/usr/local/openssl-1.0.2h shared
make depend
make
make install
```

Now symlink OS X's openssl to your new and updated openssl:

```
ln -s /usr/local/openssl-1.0.2h/bin/openssl /usr/local/bin/openssl
```

Close terminal, open a new session,  and verify OS X is using your new openssl:

```
openssl version -a
```

Comment: If you're trying to install .NET core on OS X you should wrap it in Docker.

Comment: After doing all this:
OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016
built on: May 15 2016
platform: darwin64-x86_64-llvm

Comment: Creating a symlink in the following way worked for me:  
`ln -s /usr/local/openssl-1.0.2h/bin/openssl /usr/local/bin/openssl`. 
  
After restarting your Terminal session, type `which openssl` to make sure you are using the updated 1.0.2 version (`/usr/local/bin/openssl`) instead of the built-in one (`/usr/bin/openssl`).

Comment: I followed these instructions but when I type in which openssl, I get (/opt/local/bin/openssl). How do I get it to be /usr/local/bin/openssl?

Comment: I followed these instructions (thank you so much for the step-by-step), and it still said 0.9.8. Thank you to Olivier for the alternate linking method that worked.

Comment: this one saved me

Comment: Still doesn't work: a new version of OpenSSL is installed. But- it is not used by apps such as Composer. 

 
$ openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018

However output from Composer diagnose says otherwise.   

$ composer diagnose
Checking composer.json: WARNING
No license specified, it is recommended to do so. For closed-source software you may use "proprietary" as license.
Checking platform settings: WARNING
The OpenSSL library (0.9.8r) used by PHP does not support TLSv1.2 or TLSv1.1.
If possible you should upgrade OpenSSL to version 1.0.1 or above.

Comment: how do I uninstall something installed like this??

Answer (score 51):

Just execute `brew info openssl`and read the information where it says:

> If you need to have this software first in your PATH run: `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: `brew info openssl` gave the same helpful information for me. Running the suggested command above and then running `source ~/.bash_profile` or opening a new terminal solved it for me.

Comment: FINALLY. This also worked for me. The other answers above did not!

Comment: or `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`

Comment: This did not work. I'm getting the same message again.

Answer (score 22):

## If migrating your mac breaks homebrew:

I migrated my mac, and it unlinked *all* my homebrew installs - including OpenSSL. This broke `gem install`, which is how I first noticed the problem and started trying to repair this.

After a million solutions (when migrating to OSX Sierra - 10.12.5), the solution ended up being comically simple:

```
brew reinstall ruby
brew reinstall openssl
```

Edit much later: as Gal Bracha noted in the comments, you ?might? need to delete `/usr/local/opt/openssl` before doing the reinstalls, just to be safe. I didn't need to at the time, but if you're still having trouble, give that a try.

Comment: And a year later, this happened to me migrating my Mac, and your fix worked for me as well.  Thanks so much; I was getting to the point of considering wiping my new Mac and doing a fresh install and setting everything up again manually.

Comment: @David glad I could keep you from going over the brink! I almost did the same.

Comment: You might also need to delete this folder before doing the above.
`rm -rf /usr/local/opt/openssl`

Comment: I would kiss you if you were next to me. This is what worked for me after 3 hrs of struggle.

Answer (score 10):

The solution above from edwardthesecond worked for me too on Sierra

```
 brew install openssl
 cd /usr/local/include 
 ln -s ../opt/openssl/include/openssl 
 ./configure && make
```

Other steps I did before were:

- installing openssl via brew

  ```
  brew install openssl
  ```
- adding openssl to the path as suggested by homebrew

  ```
  brew info openssl
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
  ```

Comment: Worked nice for me, just skipped la part './configure && make'

Answer (score 9):

After trying everything I could find and nothing worked, I just tried this:

```
touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile
```

Inside the file added this line.

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2j/bin/openssl"
```

now it works :)

```
Jorns-iMac:~ jorn$ openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
built on: reproducible build, date unspecified
//blah blah
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/local/etc/openssl"

Jorns-iMac:~ jorn$ which openssl
/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl
```

Comment: This is a really simple solution and I was pretty hopeful that it would work for me but no luck here. Even after updating my PATH and restarting my shell session `which openssl` still points to `/usr/bin/openssl`

Comment: In order to get this working I had to edit my .bash_profile as well. But the only thing that worked was telling it to look in /usr/local/bin instead of /usr/bin. I did this by adding `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

Comment: For this to work, you need to add `/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin`, *without* the `/openssl` on the end, to the *front* of the PATH, not the end:

`PATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH`

Using `/usr/local/opt/openssl` instead of `/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/$version` means you'll automatically keep the most up-to-date version in your $PATH without having to change it every time you upgrade.

Comment: After hours of dumbness this did the trick for me along with @MarkReed's additional notes

Comment: I was able to use this and get it working for me. Thank you. I have 1.0.2q version of openssl.

Answer (score 8):

I have a similar case. I need to install openssl via brew and then use pip to install mitmproxy. I get the same complaint from `brew link --force`. Following is the solution I reached: (without force link by brew)

```
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib 
CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig 
pip install mitmproxy
```

This does not address the question straightforwardly. I leave the one-liner in case anyone uses pip and requires the openssl lib.

Note: the `/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib` paths are obtained by `brew info openssl`

Comment: Found this one useful for installing pysqlcipher

Comment: Useful for installing `cryptography`.  I was missing the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` variable

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me:

```
 brew install openssl
 cd /usr/local/include 
 ln -s ../opt/openssl/include/openssl .
```

Comment: This worked for me, trying to compile PHP 7.2.1 with phpbrew on Mac OS High Sierra - Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

By default, homebrew gave me OpenSSL version 1.1 and I was looking for version 1.0 instead. This worked for me.

To install version 1.0:

```
brew install https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb
```

Then I tried to symlink my way through it but it gave me the following error:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2t/include/openssl /usr/bin/openssl
ln: /usr/bin/openssl: Operation not permitted
```

Finally linked openssl to point to 1.0 version using brew switch command:

```
brew switch openssl 1.0.2t
Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2t
Opt link created for /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2t
```

Comment: Calling Non-checksummed download of openssl formula file from an arbitrary URL is disabled!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem while trying to install newer version of ruby 2.6.5 
https://github.com/kelaberetiv/TagUI/issues/86 helps me to solve the problem. This if for macOS catalina Version 10.15.1

Basically, I did `update and upgrade` homebrew and install openssl and install ruby.

```
brew update && brew upgrade
brew install openssl
```

Then create these 2 symlinks

```
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/
```

then installed ruby 2.6.5

Answer (score 1):

Note: this no longer works due to https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/pull/612

I had the same problem today. I uninstalled (unbrewed??) openssl 1.0.2 and installed 1.0.1 also with homebrew. Dotnet new/restore/run then worked fine.

Install openssl 101:
brew install homebrew/versions/openssl101 
Linking:
brew link --force homebrew/versions/openssl101

Comment: This did it! Seems that 1.0.2 didn't want to link. Next question is why does .netcore suggest something that is not recommended in the community.

Comment: 1.0.2 worked for me on another mac a few days ago, so maybe there is a recent brew or openssl change. Anyway, for dot net core, we are good :)

Comment: The github link posted by @bartonjs shows that brew was updated just a few days ago. Looking at the commit, the change is ` if HOMEBREW_PREFIX.to_s == "/usr/local" && keg.name == "openssl"` so I'm guessing that the 1.0.1 version uses a different HOMEBREW_PREFIX.

Comment: didn't work for me, still gives error `Refusing to link: openssl101
Linking keg-only openssl101 means you may end up linking against the insecure,
deprecated system OpenSSL while using the headers from Homebrew's openssl101.
Instead, pass the full include/library paths to your compiler e.g.:
  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl101/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl101/lib`

Comment: This answer is no longer correct given the change made by homebrew devs at https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/pull/612

Comment: This is awful... don't do this but... vi /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/link.rb (line 28) `if false &&`. Then `brew install --force openssl`. Don't do this, I'm likely a terrible person for even suggesting it.

Answer (score 1):

for me this is what worked...

I edited the ./bash_profile and added below command

export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"

Answer (score 1):

```sh
export https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:1087 http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:1087 all_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:1080
```

works for me

and I think it can solve all the problems like 
`Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443: Connection refused`

Answer (score 1):

The solution might be updating some tools.

Here's my scenario from 2020 with Ruby and Python:

I needed to install Python 3 on Mac and things escalated. In the end, updating homebrew, node and python lead to the problem with openssl. I did not have openssl 1.0 anymore, so I couldn't "brew switch" to it.
So what was still trying to use that old 1.0 version?

It tuned out it was Ruby 2.5.5.
So I just **installed Ruby 2.5.8** and removed the old one.

Other things you can try if this is not enough: Use rbenv and pyenv. Clean up gems and formulas. Update homebrew, node, yarn. Upgrade bundler. Make sure your .bash_profile (or equivalent) is set up according to each tool's instructions. Reopen the terminal.