# Error installing .net core on mac

Tags: .net, macos, .net-core

I am unable to execute this command successfully (while following early part of this [tutorial](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos)

```
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/
```

The error I get is

> ln: /usr/local/lib/: No such file or directory

How can I fix this?

I've tried referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38670295/brew-refusing-to-link-openssl) post, but am unable to follow it.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions are out of date, sadly. The steps that worked for me (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38706045/3191599)):

```
brew update
brew install openssl
sudo install_name_tool -add_rpath /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.0/System.Security.Cryptography.Native.dylib
```

According to the [issue on Github](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3964), there will be an update in the future that resolves this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Need to specify where the required file is located to map the path

**> sudo install_name_tool -add_rpath /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.0/System.Security.Cryptography.Native.dylib**

**
Above solution will work if you having the same folder structure for installed dotnet core.

**/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.0/System.Security.Cryptography.Native.dylib**

kindly check the location of the file System.Security.Cryptography.Native.dylib in your system, however folder structure or packages may get change as per the updates. In my case the path was

> **/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.2/System.Security.Cryptography.Native.dylib**

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using this command: sudo mkdir /usr/local/lib/