# dotnet core in macOS: "The type initializer for 'Crypto' threw an exception"

Tags: .net, macos, .net-core

I followed the instructions on the [.NET Core website](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos), but got this error. Apparently there are some pre-reqs which are missing. Any idea how to install those?

```
mymac:~ naveen.vijay$ dotnet new

Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Crypto' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'CryptoInitializer' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'System.Security.Cryptography.Native': The specified module could not be found.
 (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at Interop.CryptoInitializer.EnsureOpenSslInitialized()
   at Interop.CryptoInitializer..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Interop.Crypto..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Interop.Crypto.GetRandomBytes(Byte* buf, Int32 num)
   at System.IO.Path.GetCryptoRandomBytes(Byte* bytes, Int32 byteCount)
   at System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.InternalAbstractions.TemporaryDirectory..ctor()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.EnvironmentAbstractions.DirectoryWrapper.CreateTemporaryDirectory()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.NuGetPackagesArchiver..ctor()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ConfigureDotNetForFirstTimeUse(INuGetCacheSentinel nugetCacheSentinel)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ProcessArgs(String[] args, ITelemetry telemetryClient)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
Abort trap: 6
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The install instructions for macOS are out of date. See this discussion on Github: [SSL Fails to Link Using Brew](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3964).

I ran into this myself when installing .NET Core on macOS El Capitan. The solution, from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38670295/brew-refusing-to-link-openssl), is running the following:

```
sudo install_name_tool -add_rpath /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.0/System.Security.Cryptography.Native.dylib
```

After running that command in my terminal, `dotnet new` worked fine.

Answer (score 6):

Something happened with my brew install and I had to run the following commands to create symbolic links to OpenSSL (from the .Net Core page on [Microsoft](http://microsoft.com/net/core#macos)):

```
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/ 
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/
```

Comment: this answer solved my problem encountering Crypto exception in Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 2):

Need to specify where the required file is located to map the path

> sudo install_name_tool -add_rpath /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
>   /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.0/System.Security.Cryptography.Native.dylib

Above solution will work if you having the same folder structure for installed dotnet core.

**/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.0/System.Security.Cryptography.Native.dylib**

kindly check the location of the file **System.Security.Cryptography.Native.dylib**  in your system, however folder structure or packages may get change as per the updates. In my case the path was

> /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.2/System.Security.Cryptography.Native.dylib

Comment: would you please add an explanation as to what the install_name_tool is specifically doing in this example?  Thanks!