# TypeInitializationException / SSL library issue with dotnet core and Ubuntu

Tags: c#, .net, linux, .net-core

I have a dotnet core app (`netcoreapp3.1`) that crashes with the following error on launch:

```
$ dotnet run
Unhandled exception. System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Crypto' threw an exception.
 ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'CryptoInitializer' threw an exception.
 ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'libSystem.Security.Cryptography.Native.OpenSsl' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: liblibSystem.Security.Cryptography.Native.OpenSsl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
   at Interop.CryptoInitializer.EnsureOpenSslInitialized()
   at Interop.CryptoInitializer..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Interop.CryptoInitializer.Initialize()
   at Interop.Crypto..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Interop.Crypto.EvpPkeyDestroy(IntPtr pkey)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.SafeEvpPKeyHandle.ReleaseHandle()
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.InternalRelease(Boolean disposeOrFinalizeOperation)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.Finalize()
```

I have searched for this error, but most of the discussion is from 2016.

I am using **Ubuntu 20.04**.

System info:

```sh
$ openssl version 
OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017

$ dotnet --version
5.0.101

$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   foca
```

How can I run this application?

---

Update, I ran `sudo apt-get install lsb-core`.

It still does not work, but `lsb_release -a` is now different:

```sh
$ lsb_release -a 
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

---

Related, but macOS [dotnet core in macOS: "The type initializer for 'Crypto' threw an exception"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39133356/dotnet-core-in-macos-the-type-initializer-for-crypto-threw-an-exception)

Comment: `consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable` Have you done that?

Comment: @mjwills That will help show the search paths attempted but does not fix the issue.

Comment: What happened when you set it?

Comment: @mjwills It still crashes but shows more diagnostic information

Comment: Does https://askubuntu.com/a/230773 fix it?

Comment: @mjwills Unfortunately it does not

Answer (score 0):

A hacky solution is to copy the `5.x` libraries into `3.x`:

```sh
sudo cp /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.2/libSystem.Security.Cryptography.Native.OpenSsl.a /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/3.1.11/libSystem.Security.Cryptography.Native.OpenSsl.a

sudo cp /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.2/libSystem.Security.Cryptography.Native.OpenSsl.so /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/3.1.11/libSystem.Security.Cryptography.Native.OpenSsl.so
```