# Elasticsearch Python client SSLError on Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, ssl, urllib3

Our devops recently turned on SSL on our in-house ElasticSearch servers, while our Ubuntu dev boxes are connecting to it fine, but it's causing `SSLError` on Mac dev boxes (running Django).

```
SSLError at /search
ConnectionError(EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590)) caused by: SSLError(EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590))
```

What I know so far:

- Not limited to El Capitan, also breaks on earlier version
- We can connect to other ES service over https, our devops told me our ES service has higher https requirements
- Openssl v0.9.8 has handshake problem on the ES service
- Openssl v1.0.1 works fine on the ES service

There are many posts online around this problem but none helped.

I have tried:

- brew link --force openssl (but EL Capitan is stopping it), none of the solutions worked from [Homebrew refusing to link OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38670295/brew-refusing-to-link-openssl)
- adding `/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib` to `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`
- upgrading python from 2.7.10 to 2.7.12
- rebuilding virtualenv

None of the above worked...

Questions:

- Is it due to OpenSSL version?
- Is it due to Python version due to _ssl.c?
- How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Finally nailed it, basically you will have to install Python that has updated openssl

check in Python cmd

```
import ssl
print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION
```

It should print 0.9.x

Now to update:

1. `brew install openssl`, don't worry about the linking if it rejects, make sure it's `>=1.x.x`
2. 'brew install python --with-brewed-openssl`
3. recreate virtualenv by specifying the brewed version of Python, eg. `mkvirtualenv --python=/usr/.../Cellar/python/bin/python <project>`