# M1 Mac how to install llvm

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, llvm, apple-m1

I have done everything possible to install eo-learn but it is not working
using Conda won't work
closest I got to making it work was with pip but I get stuck while trying to install numba

steps taken

```
brew install llvm

export LLVM_CONFIG=/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/llvm-config

LLVM_CONFIG=/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/llvm-config pip install numba

LLVM_CONFIG=/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/llvm-config pip install llvmlite which is the major dependency breaking for now

brew link llvm 
Warning: Refusing to link macOS provided/shadowed software: llvm
If you need to have llvm first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find llvm you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/include"

I have added the flags

brew link -force llvm
Warning: Refusing to link macOS provided/shadowed software: llvm
If you need to have llvm first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find llvm you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/include"
```

I have done everything I know someone please help me

can some tell me how I can get the installer to recognise it

Comment: I googled the first error message and found [this blog posting](https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/02/24/installing-llvm-clang-on-osx/) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38670295/fnord).

Comment: Is the end goal to use Tensorflow. Because it seems I just got that working.

Answer (score 17):

I was able to install llvmlite on my m1 with the following steps:

```
arch -arm64 brew install llvm@11
LLVM_CONFIG="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm@11/11.1.0_4/bin/llvm-config" arch -arm64 pip install llvmlite
```

It's important to:

- specify version 11 of llvm (or check if higher llvm version still compatible with your llvmlite).
- make sure you're installing both with the same arch `arm64`.
- make sure your LLVM_CONFIG value is correct for your system (in my case it's under `**/11.1.0_4/`) you may have a newer version or even in completly different PATH.

Comment: I think one can safely remove the `arch -arm64` parts, that should be the default. The reason `llvm@11` (and not the latest, 14 version) is needed is because the most recent llvmlite version (0.37.0) requires it.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this link. https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/02/24/installing-llvm-clang-on-osx/

Adding Homebrew llvm/clang to path worked for me.

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the pain of `clangd` not handling M1 threads well:
https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues/1119

That issue is fixed in llvm 15, which is released as an rc1, but Brew does not currently install that version. Installing via `brew install --HEAD llvm` has never worked for me because the build fails and I'm not sure how to address this.

In case it's helpful to others, I was able to install llvm 15 pretty easily via the `clang+llvm-15.0.0-rc1-arm64-apple-darwin21.0.tar.xz` release artifact found in the github release folder here:

https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/tag/llvmorg-15.0.0-rc1

Note that you'll want to use the `arm64` version if you have an M1 Mac, not the x86_64 version. The latter would be useful for people with older Intel Macs.

### LLVM Release Artifact Install Steps

Here are the steps I used to install LLVM via their release artifacts on an M1 Mac:

1. Download and untar the arm64 release artifact from the [llvmorg-15.0.0-rc1](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/tag/llvmorg-15.0.0-rc1) release page to some path in your home directory:
   [clang+llvm-15.0.0-rc1-arm64-apple-darwin21.0.tar.xz](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/download/llvmorg-15.0.0-rc1/clang+llvm-15.0.0-rc1-arm64-apple-darwin21.0.tar.xz)
2. Update your `PATH` variable to point to the resulting `clang+llvm-15.0.0-rc1-arm64-apple-darwin21.0/bin` directory.
3. Verify that `clangd` works by running `clangd --version`. You should see output verifyin `15.0.0`. For me, running `clangd` initially failed due to the binary not being able to find a `libzstd` shared object. `brew install zstd` installed the dependency. You may need to install other dependencies.

Once all dependencies are resolved and your `PATH` is updated, you should see this (again, verify the version to make sure you are picking up the expected `clangd`, not the system, Brew, or other version on your system):

```
$  clangd --version                                           
clangd version 15.0.0
Features: mac+xpc
Platform: arm64-apple-darwin21.6.0
```

Now `clang`, `clangd`, etc. should be used via your `PATH`. I needed this updated `clangd` for my `coc-nvim` plugin, for which I explicitly point to `clangd` for nvim via my `coc-settings.json` file:

```
$ cat ~/.config/nvim/coc-settings.json                       
{
  "clangd.arguments": ["-j=4"],
  "clangd.path": "/<some_path>/clang+llvm-15.0.0-rc1-arm64-apple-darwin21.0/bin/clangd"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The clang+llvm-14.0.5-x86_64-apple-darwin.tar.xz build in [github](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases) can work on M1

Comment: Someone with an M1 Mac will surely want the `arm64` version, not the `x86_64` version.