# "../MacOS/Python is loading libcrypto in an unsafe way" issues loading libssl on MAC m1 bigsur

Tags: macos, cryptography, libssl

As the title suggests I am having issues running [python-bitcoinlib example code](https://github.com/petertodd/python-bitcoinlib/blob/master/examples/spend-p2pkh-txout.py). When I first run I get a permission denied message. I run it as root and I get the following:

```
WARNING: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python is loading libcrypto in an unsafe way
[1]    32672 abort      python3 ./spend-p2pkh-txout.py
```

I uninstalled `libssl` with brew and reinstalled and I still running into the same issue. Is anyone else encountering this error?

Answer (score 0):

As per [this gist](https://gist.github.com/aklap/e885721ef15c8668ed0a1dd64d2ea1a7) (which links to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38670295/homebrew-refusing-to-link-openssl)), it seems "unsafe" means the library files are not in `/usr/local/lib`.

To fix this, you can just link them there:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib /usr/local/lib/
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib /usr/local/lib/
```